# CSS and JS minification doesn't work with gulp-filter, gulp-csso, gulp-uglify

Tags: javascript, gulp, minify, gulp-uglify, gulp-filter

I'm working thorough johnpapa's course on automation with Gulp and seem to hit a weird wall: when I'm trying to run the CSS and JS concatenation and minification task it fails to do the minification.

This is the task:

```
gulp.task('optimize', ['inject'], function () {

    var assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: ''});
    var cssFilter = $.filter(['**/*.css'], {restore: true});
    var jsFilter = $.filter(['**/*.js'], {restore: true});

    return gulp
        .src(config.indexFile)
        .pipe($.rename('test.jsp'))
        .pipe($.plumber())
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe($.csso())
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe($.uglify())
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe($.useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.indexLocation))
        ;
});
```

`inject` is the task that injects css and js references to the index file (works correctly), `$` is `require('gulp-load-plugins')({lazy: true})` and `config.indexFile` is `index.jsp`.

My file structure (unlike the one in the course) is:

```
- ModuleDir
    - dist
        - css
            - lib.css
            - app.css
        - fonts
        - images
        - js
            - lib.js
            - app.js
    - css
    - js
    - web-app
        - InnerDir
            - index.jsp
            - test.jsp
    - package.json, bower.json, etc. (all the required files)
```

Basically, index.jsp is processed for CSS and JS library and application assets, which are minified and concatenated into lib.css, lib.js, app.css and app.js. Later all these are injected into a copy of index.jsp which is called test.jsp.

The asset gathering, concatenation and injection works splendidly. The minification - not so much...

Any ideas or pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, apparently filters no longer work that way, so I'm using gulp-if for that. Under the same premises, the working code is:

```
gulp.task('optimize', ['inject'], function () {

    var assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: ''});

    return gulp
        .src(config.indexFile)
        .pipe($.rename('test.jsp'))
        .pipe($.plumber())
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe($.if('*.css', $.csso()))
        .pipe($.if('**/lib.js', $.uglify({preserveComments: 'license', mangle: false})))
        .pipe($.if('**/app.js', $.ngAnnotate()))
        .pipe($.if('**/app.js', $.uglify()))
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe($.useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.indexLocation))
        ;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for reference useref also changed with v3.0.

Here's my code I got working with the latest versions of gulp-filters and gulp-useref. Might be handy for anyone working through JP's gulp course...

```html
gulp.task('optimise', ['inject', 'fonts', 'images'], function() {
    log('Optimising the JavaScript, CSS, HTML');
       
    // $.useref looks for  <!-- build:js js/app.js -->  in index.html and compiles until  <!-- endbuild -->
    var templateCache = config.temp + config.templateCache.file;
    var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css', {restore: true});
    var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js', {restore: true});   
       
    return gulp
        .src(config.index)
        .pipe($.plumber())                                        
        .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(templateCache, {read: false}), {
            starttag: '<!-- inject:templates:js -->'                
        }))
        .pipe($.useref({searchPath: './'}))
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe($.csso())
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe($.uglify())
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore)                                                                                     
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build));

});
```

Note: I also corrected the spelling of 'optimise' in the function name as I'm English :)

Comment: Perfect! Just what i was looking for :)